# SQL table merging

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008, I'll try my best to describe what I want to do.

Let's say I have table A that looks like this:

Table A

```
VarName  |  ValueA  |  ValueB
-----------------------------
var1     |   0.12   |   0.34
var2     |   1.456  |   5.31
var3     |   43     |    10
```

And a table B that looks like this:

Table B

```
VarName  |  ValueC  |  ValueD
-----------------------------
var1     |   0.03   |   0.04
var2     |   2.01   |   2.87
newvar   |   55     |    50
```

What I want to do is combine these tables so that the end result looks like this table C.

Table C

```
VarName  |  ValueA  |  ValueB  |  ValueC  |  ValueD
---------------------------------------------------
var1     |   0.12   |   0.34   |   0.03   |  0.04
var2     |   1.456  |   5.31   |   2.01   |  2.87
var3     |   43     |    10    |    0     |   0
newvar   |   0      |    0     |    55    |   50
```

Note that when merged, the common rows (var names) are updated with values from the other table in the columns that are not common, and variables not present in one table have their columns merged from the other table set to 0 such as newvar from table B and var3 from table A.

Does this request make sense or does it require further explanation?

Comment: What  have you tried so far?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp would seem to be what you'd want here.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
select VarName, max(ValueA), max(ValueB), max(ValueC), max(ValueD) from (
    select VarName, ValueA, ValueB, 0 as ValueC, 0 as ValueD
    from TableA
    union all
    select VarName, 0, 0, ValueC, ValueD
    from TableB
)
group by VarName
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
  VarName
  ,MAX(IValueA) AS ValueA
  ,MAX(ValueB) AS ValueB
  ,MAX(ValueC) AS ValueC
  ,MAX(ValueD) AS ValueD
FROM (  
SELECT 
  VarName
  ,ValueA
  ,ValueB
  ,0 AS ValueC
  ,0 AS ValueD
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  VarName
  ,0 AS ValueA
  ,0 AS ValueB
  ,ValueC
  ,ValueD  
FROM B
) a
GROUP BY VarName
```